# ngx-datepicker change class or remove "invalid date"

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am using ngx-datepicker and trying to update the class if date is not valid with has-error class. I am on Angular 5 and trying to do it using `[ngClass]`. If invalid date is typed in the date field it display "invalid date" within the field. Is there a way I can remove this text and apply the `has-error` class on date field ? This is how my template looks like:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 form-group"  [ngClass]="{'has-error':!isDateValid()}" >
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="dpFromDate.toggle()">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
        <input id="fromDate" name="fromDate"  #dpFromDate="bsDatepicker" bsDatepicker [(ngModel)]="fromDate" type="text" [bsConfig]="{containerClass:'theme-dark-blue'}"
            class="form-control">
    </div>
```

Comment: the question is not very clear, what is `dpFromDate` pointing to? a form control or what?

Comment: I have update my question. Its template reference to bsdatepicker directive. There is not any documentation around validation on valor's site.

Comment: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker

Answer (score 3):

I set a function to handle the error. It looked something like this.

```
<input
        #dp="bsDatepicker"
        [bsConfig]="bsConfig"
        (change)="isInvalidDate($event)"
      />
```

Then it's handled

```
isInvalidDate( event ){
let test = event.target.value;

if ( test == 'Invalid date' ){
  event.target.value = formatDate (new Date () , 'MM/dd/yyyy' , 'en'); // Change it here
}}
```